# checking custom fields like images and ignore them if they are empty

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I have five custom fields for loading images but all of them are not required. I mean the user can upload a random number of images from 1 to 5. I am stuck in a simple lack of concept here.  What I am missing? Here is my code

```
$img = array();

$post = get_page_by_title( $pgnr,OBJECT,'post');
$id= $post->ID;
$custom_fields = get_post_custom($id);

$images = Array("image1","image2","image3","image4","image5");
foreach($images as $image){
   if(isset($custom_fields[$image]) && (!empty($custom_fields[$image]))) {
       $img[] = $custom_fields[$image];
    }
}
echo '<div id="showcase" class="showcase">';
foreach ( $img as $value )
{
  echo '<div class="showcase-slide">';              
     echo  '<div class="showcase-content">';
         echo'<img alt="image" src="'. wp_get_attachment_url( $value ).'"  width="600"                     height="500"/>';

     echo '</div>';

  echo '<div class="showcase-thumbnail">';
  echo '<img alt="thumb" src="'.wp_get_attachment_url( $value ).'" width="140" /> ';


  echo  '</div>';
  }
 echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the array $img[] needs an index between the brackets that only increments each time values are assigned into the array.